# FileSystem Watcher- Checking if copied file is an Image

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

I'm monitoring a Folder for File creation(Copied) event using FileSystem Watcher. I only want the program to process image Files.

```
FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
watcher.Filter = "*.*";
watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(watcher_FileCreated);
watcher.Path = path;
```

So I try to create a Bitmap and avoid the file if an exception is thrown

```
private static void watcher_FileCreated(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        using (Bitmap test = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(e.FullPath)))
        {
            mytoprocesslist.add(e.FullPath);
        }

        //do my processing with image 
        Console.WriteLine(e.FullPath);
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("File Error");
    }
 }
```

This throws `Out of Memory exception` even when a valid image file is copied, which I think happens because the event was raised before the file was copied completely. How can I get over this? I only want to add the valid image files to a to do list and I will process these images one by one later.

Comment: above code does not seem to have any line which might throw out of memory. Most probably your "//do my processing with image" is throwing this error. You can add wait of 1 sec if you feel the file is not yet copied completely.

Comment: @puneet     `using (Bitmap test = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(e.FullPath)))`

Comment: I set `watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;` and to load image, I'm using `Image.FromFile(e.FullPath);` and it works, without any exception.

Comment: To the person who has downvoted this,it would be good to leave a comment.

Comment: @x... what does setting `watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName;` do?

Comment: Read this first : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.notifyfilters(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @x...  NotifyFilters.FileName checks for file name change right?

Comment: The Method `Bitmap.FromFile` creates an image and holds the resource. Then you create another image by calling `new Bitmap` that again holding a resource. Second resource you release when exit the `using` block. But the first resource is hold. It also must be released! Use two of the `using` block or remove one unnecessary `Bitmap` creation.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Can you please add it as an answer with code.

Answer (score 1):

A bit cleaner solution than a Try-Catch might be this one.
Im using this code without any exceptions raised.

```
private static bool IsImage(string path) {
      try {
        var result = false;

        using (var stream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open)) {
          stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

          var jpg = new List<string> { "FF", "D8" };
          var bmp = new List<string> { "42", "4D" };
          var gif = new List<string> { "47", "49", "46" };
          var png = new List<string> { "89", "50", "4E", "47", "0D", "0A", "1A", "0A" };
          var imgTypes = new List<List<string>> { jpg, bmp, gif, png };

          var bytesIterated = new List<string>();

          for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            var bit = stream.ReadByte().ToString("X2");
            bytesIterated.Add(bit);

            var isImage = imgTypes.Any(img => !img.Except(bytesIterated).Any());
            if (isImage) {
              result = true;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
        return result;
      } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException) {
        return false;
      }
    }
```

**Usage of code**

```
foreach (var file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(@"pathToFlowersFolder"))
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"File: {file} Result:{IsImage(file)}");
            }
```

**Edit**

After playing around i got an IO-Exception (File already in use)
After reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577889/system-ioexception-when-opening-file-with-file-openread) i'd offer you the following solution:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();
            watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(fileSystemWatcher1_Changed);
            watcher.Path = @"c:\temp";
            watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
            watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100); // <- give the Creator some time. Increase value for greate pause
            if (IsImage(e.FullPath))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("success----------->" + e.FullPath);
            }
        }
```

**Note**

This piece of code properly works on my machine. My HDD is an SSD, so you might need to increase the thread-sleeping time. It properly works for all images (jpg, bmp, gif, png) up to a size of 7 Mb (im quite sure and greater).

If this code doesnt works for you, please post the exception rather than uploading your code.

Comment: Thanks ...I will try and get back... btw i did not downvote :)

Comment: This fails to properly detect some jpg images.

Comment: Can you give me an example? Magic number for jpg should start with `FFd8`. Stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8755028/4558029) multiple times

Comment: Please see the image in this zip file http://wikisend.com/download/868908/Flowers.zip

Comment: Cant reproduce your statement. Every image in your zip is considered as a valid image with the posted code.

Comment: I'm not enumerating files like that.. Please see the complete project here http://wikisend.com/download/701754/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip

Comment: @techno Updated answer

Comment: Thanks ... will check and get back.

Answer (score 0):

For the first requirement: "I only want the program to process image files"

```
private static void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
  string strFileExt = getFileExt(e.FullPath); 

  // filter file types 
  if (Regex.IsMatch(strFileExt, @"\.png|\.jpg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)) 
  { 
      //here Process the image file 
  }
}
```

For the second requirement: "Out of Memory Exception"

Here what happens is, when the file is created (only file name and some attributes) the system is calling the created event. Then the file changed event is also called

So you have to do the processing in the changed event. Also to prevent duplicate calling you have to add a filter to your watcher.

**The following is the complete code.**

```
private void fileSystemWatcher1_Changed(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
        {

            FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(e.FullPath);
            string strFileExt = fileInfo.Extension;

            // filter file types 
            if (Regex.IsMatch(strFileExt, @"\.png|\.jpg", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase))
            {
                //here Process the image file 
                try
                {
                    using (Bitmap test = new Bitmap(Bitmap.FromFile(e.FullPath)))
                    {
                        //Do your code here.
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception error)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("File Error");
                }
            }


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = @"C:\Users\Christlin\Desktop\res";

            //To Prevent duplicated calling of changed event
            fileSystemWatcher1.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.Size;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks ... you have hooked to changed event and created event... should i hook to both events?

Comment: Based on the OPs requirements, that might not be enough. For example, I could easily disguise an image by giving it another extension (e.g. `.txt`).

Comment: @techno the changed and Form1_Load events only enough

Comment: @Christian.K thanks for the note, in that case we can even process the file without the file extension check, and handle it with the creation of a bitmap part of the code.

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph I still get `A first chance exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll` when copying like 10 images of size more than 1 MB.It seems the old issue still persists.This occurs because the images are not copied fully.

Comment: @Christian.K plz see by above comment ^

Comment: @techno You need to keep the Changed event only. Here i have tested with 6MB sized images. Can you post here your code and full exception

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph Please get the complete project here http://wikisend.com/download/701754/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph sorry... please check this http://wikisend.com/download/616644/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip... that project was modified.

Comment: @techno 'if (IsImage(e.FullPath))' function call is not required, because we have already checked the file extensions using regx. Remove that part and it will work

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph yeah... that is the modified project.. please check this one http://wikisend.com/download/616644/WindowsFormsApplication1.zip

Comment: @techno The code is working properly for me, Also you can copy the image to the destination folder, by simply copying the file. Here you are creating a bitmap and writing that created bitmap to the disk. So it is involving lot of RAM. My system here have 16GB of RAM. The code works perfectly in my machine.

Comment: @techno try to use `File.Copy(SourcePath, DestPath, true);` Because the code you have sent used 888MB of RAM for 44 hi-res Images.

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph Please see the files im trying with http://wikisend.com/download/868908/Flowers.zip

Comment: @techno Download this code and try to run it. http://wikisend.com/download/831448/FileSystemWatcherDemo.zip I can send screenshots if required

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph I'm using VS2010 .. getting 
`This project is incompatible with the current version of visual studio`

Comment: @techno I don't have VS2010, I have modified the solution file. Try to open this file, http://wikisend.com/download/154242/FileSystemWatcherDemo.zip I hope it works, if it is not opening then you can view all the source files in vs2010. Then create a new windows forms project. Add a file watcher by dragging it. Then copy the Form1.cs file contents. Change the path according to your system. Then it will work for sure.

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph Does not work.. file system watcher does not trigger any events ..

Comment: @techno have you changed the watcher Path (in the form load event)?

Comment: download the last attachment, and copy and paste the code in a new windows forms application. dont forgot to drag and drop the file watcher in the designer. try as a fresh copy. try to send a report of windows steps recorder

Comment: @techno I have attached the output and the workflow of the program, using Steps Recorder. download it from http://wikisend.com/download/957996/Program_Flow.zip

Comment: @techno okay let me know the results.

Comment: @ChristlinJoseph sure... thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: @techno Welcome :)